# (Oracle Apex ver. 12 c) How to create an LOV from one table that displays another table as results

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have to create a list of values, three separate symptoms, that would return likely illnesses from another table that has related symptoms. Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: There's no "Apex ver. 12c"; the last Apex version is 5.1.4, database is 12c. It would help if you described what you have (with some examples) and what you'd want to get. Reading that single sentence of yours, it sounds like a cascade LoV, one depending on another.

Comment: It is kinda of the opposite of cascading. I am trying to get 2 seperate lovs to give me a result from another table. 2 symptoms lov's that give a list of possible illnesses.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is simply a **report** (as well as your 2 LOV items), with a query like:

```
select * from illnesses i
where exists (select null 
              from illness_symptoms s1
              where s1.illness_id = i.illness_id
                and s1.symptom = :P123_SYMPTOM1
             )
and exists (select null 
            from illness_symptoms s2
            where s2.illness_id = i.illness_id
              and s2.symptom = :P123_SYMPTOM2
             )
```

This could in fact be a cascading LOV instead of a report, if that's what you need, with the symtom LOVs as its parents.